# Wordpress ошибка загрузка картинки

Tags: wordpress

Добрый день друзья есть такой вопрос, за 2 года первый раз столкнулся -- wordpress начал ругаться на загрузку картинок jpg и png (3.jpg
Извините, этот тип файла недопустим по соображениям безопасности.)

Для проверки в директории в файле wp-config.php отключил чтобы не ругался вот таким кодом отключил все типы define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true); )) но проблема чуток изменилась -- картинки загружаются но не видно как они выглядят в админке как будто это pdf файл )) можете подсказать кто то сталкивался с этим ? заранее извиняюсь за плохое описание

Comment: По умолчанию wp не запрещает загрузку jpg. Ищите проблему в плагинах и теме. Отключите все плагины, переключите тему на дефолтную, пересохраните пермалинки.

Comment: MIME-тип картинок проверь. Последние версии ВП его вроде проверяют для безопасности.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию щас проверю

Comment: Оказалось я сохранил jpeg как jpg из за этого  ругался и wordpress и фотошоп!

Comment: @Said вообще странно это.. Но оформи решение как ответ и потом примешь его  решённым.

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось я сохранил jpeg как jpg из за этого ругался и wordpress и фотошоп!